# Returning a letter grade given a grade-scale and a student's GPA

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment where I want to return a letter grade based on a grade-scale and a student's GPA.

I was able to successfully create a function that calculates a student's GPA and returns it, but I'm having trouble returning the corresponding letter grade.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def get_gpa(scale, points):
  for (key, data) in scale.items():
    if points <= data['high'] and points >= data['low']:
      return data['gpa']
  return 0

def calculate_gpa(scale, student):
    totalCredits = 0
    gpa = 0
    for i in student['classes']:
      classGpa = get_gpa(scale, i['points'])
      totalCredits += i['credits']
      gpa += (classGpa) * (i['credits'])
    return gpa / totalCredits

def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
  for (key, data) in grade_scale.items():
    if gpa <= data['high'] and gpa >= data['low']:
      return key
    else:
      return 'D'
```

Here is the scale:

```
grade_scale = {
 "A+": {"low": 96, "high":100,"gpa":4.0},
 "A" : {"low": 93, "high":95, "gpa":4.0},
 "A-": {"low": 90, "high":92, "gpa":3.7},

 "B+": {"low": 86, "high":89, "gpa":3.3},
 "B" : {"low": 83, "high":85, "gpa":3.0},
 "B-": {"low": 80, "high":82, "gpa":2.7},

 "C+": {"low": 76, "high":79, "gpa":2.3},
 "C" : {"low": 73, "high":75, "gpa":2.0},
 "C-": {"low": 70, "high":72, "gpa":1.7},
}
```

For example, if a student has a 3.47 GPA, the get_letter_grade_v1 function should return a "B+".

```
student123 = {
  "id": "smith123",
  "classes" : [
    {"name": "stats 100",   "points": 88, "credits": 4},
    {"name": "cs 101",      "points": 92, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "history 101", "points": 91, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "Pysch 201",   "points": 86, "credits": 4},
  ]
}
```

When I test run this student's grades for each class, it continues to return a 'D' when it should actually return a 'B+'. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code or offer some tips? Thanks!

Comment: Please complete your posting.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your code is missing a driving example, and a little ... never mind ... I just saw the problem.

Comment: Post some example input/output, and desired output for better response time from folks here on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you declare failure after looking at only one possible grade: no matter the student's score, you return a result after the first iteration of the `for` loop.

```
def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
  for (key, data) in grade_scale.items():
    if gpa <= data['high'] and gpa >= data['low']:
      return key
    else:
      return 'D'
```

Instead, you must wait until *all* checks have failed:

```
def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
  for (key, data) in grade_scale.items():
    if gpa <= data['high'] and gpa >= data['low']:
      return key

  # When every check has failed:
  return 'D'
```

---

More updates:

- You have to give the data in the proper form.  3.47 is a very low grade: your scale is percentage, but you feed it a GPA.  The C- cutoff is 70, and 3.47 is simply awful.
- Even then, this will return a `D`: your posted case has an average of 89.25, which does not appear in any grade range.  Adjust your limits to account for a float score, or convert (floor or ceiling) the average as your grading scale requires.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out. However, when I test-run the functions, it continues to give me a 'D' for a student who has a 3.47 GPA rather than a 'B+'. I suspect there is a flaw in my last function.

Comment: You have to feed in the 0-100 average; your grade_scale is made for percentages, not grade-points.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up hard-coding the values, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what Prune pointed out the error is that you are comparing the GPA against data['high'] and data['low'] in get_letter_grade_v1 which are in percent not GPA.

Also the grade is not recoverable from the GPA since A+ and A have the same GPA in the grade_scale.